# How can I solvent exchange from water to alcohol?

Tags: solvents

Given an aqueous colloidal solution, is there a way to transfer the colloidal particles into an alcohol (assuming the colloidal particles are also stable in the alcohol)? I see in the literature that lyophilizing the aqueous solution and re-dispensing the colloidal particles is an option, but is there a method to perform this all in the wet phase?

Comment: It would help other potential answerers if you would cite the literature.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a colloid, rather than a true solution, put the water-based mixture in a [dialysis membrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialysis_(biochemistry)) of appropriate pore size and immerse it in concentrated alcohol. The water will dissolve into the alcohol, while alcohol slowly seeps in to displace the water, but the colloidal particles cannot get through the pores. Depending on how little water is desired in the final product, this step may be repeated multiple times.

For some materials, inexpensive [cellophane sausage casing](https://www.waltonsinc.com/casings-netting/cellulose-casings) may be suitable.